# Random background? Android

Tags: android, random, background

I'm trying to set random bg for my activity, but my app is force close when I get in my activity. What is the problem with this code?

In my first activity, you get the camera intent after clicking the START button, and when you take the picture about yourself, you get to a another activity, where for result you get a random image answer in the bg. It's like a application where you take a pic about yourself, and the program will answer for you that you're looking good, or not, something like that. The answer is provided as an image, in the imageView, and this is why I need random bg change.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03};

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Get a random between 0 and images.length-1
        int imageId = (int)(Math.random() * images.length);

// Set the image
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(images[imageId]);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-012012013013/01201201201");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

So what is the problem? I get no error for the code, just force close, when I take the picture, and get in to the another activity.

Comment: Can you post a logcat output of when the app closes?

Comment: is this the activity that error occurs?

Comment: I posted my logcat below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are setting the content view after declaring that images array, try putting the array after 'setContentView'. Or make the array a class varible and and initialize it in OnCreate.

If that doesn't help try running the background image setting code line on the main UI Thread by calling 'runOnUIThread' and passing in a 'new Runnable' as a parameter.

Try this instead:

```
            public static Random randomGenerator = new Random();

            @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

                    int[] images = {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03};


                ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

              // Get a random between 0 and images.length-1
                int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(images.length);
                final int imageId = images[randomNumber];

                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                               // Set the image
                               mImageView.setBackgroundResource(images[imageId]);
                          }
                     });

                // Create the interstitial.
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-012012013013/01201201201");

                // Create ad request.
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

                // Begin loading your interstitial.
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
```